# how to implement a card UI like chrome on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a card UI like chrome on Android.
How should I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very vague question, and you may want to try a simple Google search next time.

Check this out though, may be what you're looking for:
http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/

Comment: 404 url not found :(

Comment: again, google is your friend: https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android